# How to check if "all" Textboxes are empty (not individual ones)

Tags: vba, loops, excel, foreach

I've got a form in MS.Excel (VBA) with two multipages. There are multiple textboxes on both multipages. The textboxes on the second page are all starting with "txtM" plus an ascending number (txtM1, txtM2 etc.). On "Save" i'd ONLY like to remember the user if ALL of the textboxes on the second multipage (index = 1) are emtpy. Its perfectly ok if some of them are empty but a complete set of emtpy textboxes suggest, that the user simply forgot to click on the second "tab" of the multipage.

i've already tried something (see below) but have not managed to find a proper solution so far.

```
For Each crtl In Me.Controls
    If crtl.Name Like "txtM*" Then
        If crtl.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "dont forget .... blablabla"
                Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next
```

thx & greetings,
zoidie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Dim allEmpty As Boolean
allEmpty = True

For Each crtl In Me.Controls
    If crtl.Name Like "txtM*" Then
        If Trim(crtl.Value) <> "" Then
            allEmpty = False
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

If allEmpty Then
    MsgBox "dont forget .... blablabla"
    Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1
    Exit Sub
End If
```